# Receiving a File failed when run on webRTC RTCDataChannel

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

I created a simple webRTC File transfer between 2 users . I followed this java script
https://gist.github.com/johannesMatevosyan/3c3904d183cf11f0d4a3/

when i upload a file i can browse a file and showing `Sending... 100%` complete . But on another user i can see that `Receiving... NaN%` . why `NaN%` ? I can't see any links to download the file as per : `function saveFile(meta, data)` .

So i think the receiving part is failing  . I took firefox console log and i can see that :

Log :

```
TypeError: currentFile is undefined
openDataChannel/dataChannel.onmessage()
```

what is wrong in this code ? I streaming my camera using `getUserMedia` API also with this code . Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you check if `currentFileMeta.size` has something? Also, i think that script's code should go inside `$(document).ready(function() {...})` (at least the declarations and event binding functions)

Comment: when i print the `currentFileMeta.size` i can see like   `Receiving file size =  undefined` , inside the ` case "start":` switch case . why the size is undefined ? any meta  problem ?

Comment: Try declaring those variables (currentFile, currentFileMeta...) inside `openDataChannel()` function, because they are used only there.

Comment: i tried the variables inside the function but same result

Comment: Any problem when i stream my camera ? like ` RTCPeerConnection my_Connection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration,{optional:[{RtpDataChannels: true}]});
 // Setup stream listening
 my_Connection.addStream(stream); `

Comment: No problem there I think. And you receive the message `start` so the DataChannel is working. I'm out of ideas, but I'm sure it is related with Javascript

Comment: yeah . I can stream the videos and i can also chat . But when i send a File , in my sending user ..i can see sending ..100% complete but at the time in another user receiving... NaN%  . Anything i missing?

Comment: and what is the use of hasFileApi() .. they are not calling this  function anywhere . any idea about this ?

Comment: About NaN: `0 / 0 == NaN` in JS, so I suspect `end` and `file.size` are both `0` in the following line: `var percentage = Math.floor((end / file.size) * 100);`

Comment: But sending file is sucesss . Why it is not receiving ? any decode problem ?

Comment: i created a another discussion with this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267559/sending-success-but-receive-failing-in-webrtc-file-transfer